# AS3: startDrag firing mouse_up/mouse_click events

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

As I started developing mobile apps for iOS/Android using Adobe AIR I encountered strange problem (or feature).

If you create Sprite and make it draggable using startDrag/stopDrag inside MOUSE_DOWN/MOUSE_UP event handlers, everything works. But if you add another listener MOUSE_CLICK to the same object, it starts to fire together with MOUSE_UP. Logically this behavior is all right. What I need is to prevent firing MOUSE_CLICK handler when user drags the Sprite (startDrag) and I need it to fire when user did not drag the Sprite.

What I'm trying to create is a small thumbnail bar which is draggable and after clicking on concrete thumbnail its large version/image opens up. This is actually not possible as MOUSE_CLICK fires everytime user drags whole thumbnail bar so large image opens up everytime.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a flag that specifies if you're in drag mode or not.  If the user holds down for a certain amount of time (e.g. 300 msec), then set the flag and subsequently ignore the end `MOUSE_CLICK` event.  Note that we use a 1 msec timoute in the `MOUSE_UP` handler to let the events finish before the flag is reset.  Note also that you don't really need the click handler; you can call a pseudo-click-handler in your `MOUSE_UP` handler if `dragInProgress==false`.

```
private var dragTime:int = 300;
private var dragInProgress:Boolean = false;
private var dragInProgressInt:int;

function handleMouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    dragInProgressInt = setTimeout(function():void
    {
        dragInProgress = true;
    }, dragTime);

    // Start drag, etc.
}

function handleMouseUp(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    clearTimeout(dragInProgressInt);
    setTimeout(function():void
    {
        dragInProgress = false;
    }, 1);

    // End drag, etc.
}

function handleMouseClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (!dragInProgress)
    {
        // Handle the real click
    }
}
```

The logical next step would be to wait e.g. 300 msecs before even starting the drag in the first place; this would avoid unnecessary starting/stopping of the drag operation when all the users wants is to click.

*Edit: Corrected error in references to timeout name.*

Comment: Thanks. This will probably do the trick. Firstly I wanted to create my own MOUSE_UP/_MOVE/_DOWN handler (no usage of startDrag/stopDrag). I wanted to hear someone else's idea :)

Comment: Actually this works but sometimes users just keeps dragging the bar so the CLICK event fires because they keep touching the screen while reading. This causes accidental fire of CLICK event :(

Comment: @MaRmAR: If you copied/pasted that code directly, there was an error.  The references to the timeout were incorrect; I've fixed that.